# Samba, guest account for sharing user home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I have a user named **vbox**, created to manage the Orable VirtualBox on my Ubuntu Server 14.10.

I want to share the **/home/vbox/VirtualBox\ VMs/** to be able to share this files via samba.

I created this configuration in **/etc/samba/smb.conf**:

```
[vms]
path = /home/vbox/VirtualBox\ VMs/
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
guest only = yes
read only = no
guest account = vbox
force group = vboxusers
```

I need to grant **guest** accesss to this share (vms), but every file created using the guest user must be wrote using the user **vbox**.

The problem is that, when I access this share, MS Windows shows an error.

At samba log files I'm getting this:

```
[2015/02/02 13:51:38.899982,  0] ../source3/smbd/service.c:792(make_connection_snum)
canonicalize_connect_path failed for service vms, path /home/vbox/VirtualBox\ VMs
```

My environment is:

```
- Ubuntu Server 14.10
- Samba 4.1.11-Ubuntu
```

How can I solve my problem above?

Comment: first, are you prompted for a username/password? have you tried quoting the path instead of escaping the space? do you really need the space at all?

Comment: @FrankThomas that's the solution, quoting!!!! Thanks, please post your comment as a Answer and I'll accept it.